# Checking form submit using conditional?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

Is there a way to check if a form is submitted using an if statement?

I am trying to write a function that no matter what the user does, information is always recieved and displayed to them. But if they user submits a form, it sends that data to the database and updates it first.

I've been trying to find events or methods to help me with this, but couldn't seem to find anything helpful.

function getData(){

```
if ( FORM SUBMITTED ) {
    //POST and send
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = useResponse;
    request.send(str);
}

//GET and display
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onreadystatechange = useResponse;
request.send(null);
```

}

EDIT: I am not refreshing the page. I forgot to mention that I am doing this using AJAX. When the page loads, this function runs initially (which displays the form data). But I do not want the form to send any data since I'm just loading the page and not actually submitting anything.

After the page is loaded and I click submit, this function is called. What I need is AJAX to send the form data via POST, then redisplay it (the script above outlines the function).

The form when submitted just calls the function:
`action="javascript:getData()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're asking because if a form is submitted then the browser is loading a new HTTP response which may or may not know anything about an HTML form which led to its generation.

**[Edit]**

It looks like the "getData" function is doing too many things, I would create separate functions to handle the "get" and "post" requests, for example:

```
<body>
  <form name="form" action="#">...</form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var getData = function() {
      // XHR GET data and update DOM...
    };
    getData();
    var sendData = function() {
      // XHR POST form encoded data from form input elements...
    };
    document.form.onsubmit = function() {
      sendData();
      getData();
      return false; // Block the actual form submit event.
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

The [jQuery serialize() function](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) demonstrates what is needed to encode the form data programmatically.

Comment: I'm not refreshing the page, but rather using action="javascript:getData()" to run the function. I'm using AJAX to send the form data without a page refresh. See my above edit.

Comment: Oh ok! Duh! That totally makes sense. I don't know why I was trying to force it all into one function. So am I correct in guessing that it is not possible to check if a form is submitted inside an if statement?

Comment: @Dasaru: as far as I know, the only way to know if a form is being submitted is when its "submit" event fires, which means its "onsubmit" handler is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I hope I'm understanding you correctly. You basically want to (conditionally) POST to one URL and GET from another one (or the same one) in serial?

If that's the case, your code would look something like...

```
var get = function(callback) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open = req.open('GET', url);
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (...) {
      callback(req.responseText);
    }
  };
  req.send();
};

var exec = function(callback) {
  if (FORM_SUBMITTED) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', url);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (...) {
        get(callback);
      }
    };
    req.send();
  } else {
    get(callback);
  }
};

exec(function(data) {
  console.log('request(s) complete, here's the response: '+data);
});
```

Since XHR is only really worth-while when using it asynchronously, you have to nest some callbacks to make sure everything happens in serial, otherwise, the GET may complete before the POST.

Comment: I'm fairly new at programming, so I'm not sure what you are doing here.